# IE 8 and server Ubuntu

Tags: internet-explorer, ubuntu

I have a application web (jee) on my desktop, and also I deploy it as .war on my server     Ubuntu 14.0.4. I use IE11 to test it.

On my desktop (wind 10) when i run my application and use IE11 it works fine and changing compatibility of IE11 to IE8 and also works fine. But when I test the application from the server changing compatibility of my browser to IE8 it give me a error.

I was wondering if there's any relation between IE (browser) and server Linux , or I should change something  ?

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have put my application web (jee) in a server distance (ubuntu), when i test it using IE11 as broweser it work just fine but when i change comatibility of IE11 to IE8 my application give a error. but when a test localy with the same condition i don't get any error.